# Error logging into SQL Azure using manage link on Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have logged into Azure and navigated to Database link. I created a new database using "create' on the azure portal. Now i try to test connectivity. It fails. So i try to debug by clicking on "manage". Here i enter the database name user id and password. It fails, stating "Login is disabled or credentials are invalid"

I am using windows azure in conjunction with Visual Studio express (trial edition). I have tried with checking the "allow other windows azure services.." box and also by providing the IP designated to the db server in firewall rules. In both cases i get the same error.

This effort is part of deploying the sample VS 2010 windows azure web application on azure. It works fine on the emulator, but fails when actually deployed, at the time for registering a user. I have changed the default connection string to point to SQL azure as described @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh369932.aspx#SQLAzure.

Any pointers would be appreciated

regards
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the test of connectivity is failing it is extremely likely that your IP address is not correctly configured in your firewall rules.  You will need to add or edit a rule to permit you to access the database. Note that your IP address may have changed since you first configured the firewall rule.

The firewall rule popup screen will tell you which ip address you are currently using.  I have observed that this may be wrong if I was already logged into the management portal before BT reset my ip address.  If you simply log out and log back into the management portal you can confirm the ip address you are currently using and ensure that it is permitted to access the database.

This should resolve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Hello,I removed the IP rule and tried again (as i thought firewall is not present as i am working from home). In that case i get error "Firewall check failed. Cannot open server 'xxx' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx' is not allowed to access the server....". I then set IP rule.Logged out, logged in. No luck. The error now is "Login is disabled or credentials are invalid".  Any other pointers? Thank you again..

Answer (score 1):

I too had similar problem earlier,
And now it is solved.
The UserId, is youruserid@servername
You can see your userid, under Show connection strings link

And password is the password which you entered, during your database creation.